# Firebase CLI: database:set keeps complaining about 'Path must begin with /'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-tools

According to [the CLI docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#database_commands) and its own `help` command, I just need to pass it the path (which I assume is the path on the project), my json file, and any options. So this is what I do (while I'm in the folder containing the json data):

`firebase database:set --project MyProject / myJsonData.json`

where I want `/` to be the root of my project, I want to wipe out existing data and replace it with the data in `myJsonData.json`. However whenever I run this, even with changing parameter order, or putting the `/` in quotes, it tells me `Error: Path must begin with /`. The path is `/`, so I don't know what it's complaining about. There's no examples of this command in use, so I don't know what it's expecting...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out the answer is to put `//` as the path. Now I get an `Unexpected error while setting data`, but that's another issue.